# How can I use primitives in Scala?

Tags: scala, primitive-types

Can I use primitives in Scala?

The use case is for storing billions of ints, so the difference between 4 bytes (for an int) and 16 bytes (for an Integer) is important.

Comment: scala compiles to primitives when it can (Array[Int] => int[] etc.)

Comment: If you have literally billions of ints, you're likely to run into memory issues even if you use primitives, plus the size of arrays is limited on the JVM by needing an int ref to the element i.e. ~2bn elems. Think of either streaming your data or using a database instead.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you want Scala to store unboxed primitives, you could use `Array[Int]` but refrain from using any cool Scala collection method on it (because it will force boxing).

If you look for immutable collections of primitives types, you can have a look at [Debox](https://github.com/non/debox), which provides specialised Buffers, Sets and Maps. The project is still evolving but it is very promising.

Comment: I don't think calling Debox containers immutable is correct. However, Debox tries hard to provide features of Scala mutable.Buffer, Map and Set (eg. autogrowing), with good performance and in particular without boxing.

Answer (score 13):

You can use the `@specialised` annotation to let the compiler create specialised instances of a class for you. See [this article](https://web.archive.org/web/20121227215434/http://www.scala-notes.org/2011/04/specializing-for-primitive-types/).

```
class Container[@specialized(Int) T](value: T) {
  def apply(): T = value
}
```