# Is there a possibility to create a memory-efficient sequence of bits in the JVM?

Tags: scala, jvm, boolean, bit, bitset

I've got a piece of code that takes into account a given amount of features, where each feature is Boolean. I'm looking for the most efficient way to store a set of such features. My initial thought was to try and store these as a [BitSet](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/BitSet.html). But then, I realized that this implementation is [meant to be used to store numbers in bit format](http://markusjais.com/bitsets-in-scala-are-much-more-fun-than-in-java/) rather than manipulate each bit, which is something I'd like to do (see the effect of switching any feature on and off). I then thought of using a Boolean array, but apparently the [JVM uses much more memory for each Boolean element than the one bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1907318/why-is-javas-boolean-primitive-size-not-defined) it actually needs.

I'm therefore left with the question: What is the most efficient way to store a set of bits that I'd like to treat as independent bits rather than the building blocks of some number?

Comment: This question is not about Java.

Comment: how many features are we talking about that makes you worry about memory usage?

Comment: Also, I don't understand your remark "my initial thought was to try and store these as a BitSet, but then realized that this implementation is meant to be used to store numbers in bit format rather than manipulate each bit ". That is what BitSets are for: manipulating large numbers of bits in an efficient way. Individual or not. Why would BitSets be wrong for your use-case?

Comment: @LodewijkBogaards how do I manipulate bits X and Y when I have a loot of bits without calculating the number that will be represented by this bitset?

Comment: That article is outdated and the second half is spam. Still, I don’t get your conclusion that you can’t manipulate single bits. The non-spam part of that article *is* about manipulating bits.

Answer (score 2):

Please refer to this question: [boolean[] vs. BitSet: Which is more efficient?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605226/boolean-vs-bitset-which-is-more-efficient)

According to the answer of [Peter Lawrey](https://stackoverflow.com/a/608177/3767398), *boolean[]* (not *Boolean[]*) is your way to go since its values can be manipulated and it takes **only** one byte of memory per bit to store. Consider that there is no way for a JVM application to store one bit in only one bit of memory and let it be directly (array-like) manipulated because it needs a pointer to find the address of the bit and the smallest addressable unit is a byte.

The site you referenced already states that the mutable *BitSet* is the same as the *java.util.BitSet*. There is nothing you can do in Java that you can't do in Scala. But since you are using Scala, you probably want a safe implementation which is probably meant to be even multithreaded. Mutable datatypes are not suitable for that. Therefore, I would simply use an immutable *BitSet* and accept the memory cost.

However, *BitSets* have their limits (deriving from the maximum number of *int*). If you need larger data sizes, you may use *LongBitSets*, which are basically *Map<Long, BitSet>*. If you need even more space, you may nest them in another map *Map<Long, LongBitSet>*, but in that case you need to use two or more identifiers (*longs*).

Comment: boolean[] is the most efficient from a performance point of view. BitSet is more efficient for memory usage for larger sets of data.

Comment: Is `Boolean` the default Scala Boolean? What is `boolean` than?

Comment: Boolean wraps boolean and offers more methods. Check this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3728616/boolean-vs-boolean-in-java

Comment: According to http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.x/scala/Boolean.html, the Scala Boolean wraps the primitive Java boolean. This might also be interesting for you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13084290/how-can-i-use-primitives-in-scala